# Python colon not a sequence of numbers?

Tags: python, syntax

In r code, the sequence of integers from 1 to 4:

```
1:4
```

How can I replicate this in python 3? The use case is selecting from a pandas dataframe using iloc:

```
df.iloc[1:4]
```

Comment: You can use `range(1, 5)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure your current syntax allows you to select rows 1 to 3 from the dataframe as well. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

Comment: Note that `df.iloc[1:4]` is essentially just syntactic sugar for `df.iloc[slice(1,4)]`; it's unrelated to the generation of an actual sequence of integers. It's up to the particular implementation of `__getitem__` that receives that `slice` object to decide how exactly to treat it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
mylist=list(range(1,5))
print(mylist)
```

list() converts given range object into list

Comment: There is no `range` object, because your code produces a syntax error.

Comment: Yeah i agree, there should be , instead of :

Comment: Now you may check this please.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, in order to generate a range of numbers use the function [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

```
range(1, 5)
```

This will generate numbers from `1` to `4`. If you are in Python 2, `range` will give you a list, and if you are in Python 3, it will give you a `range` object.

If you are in Python 3, and you want a list, just use the `list` function to convert your range to a list

```
>>> list(range(1, 5)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm used to python 2 range. What if I want a list of numbers and not range object?

Answer (score 0):

Use `range(1, 5)` for giving you that set of integers from 1 to 4 (inclusive of both)

Answer (score 0):

To generate a range of number from 1 to 4 (inclusive), use:  `range(1, 5)` or `range(1, 4+1)`

Just a few things to note:

- The code `range(x, y)` generates a range from (and including) `x` up to (but *not* including) `y`.  If you want to include `y`, add 1 to it (as I did above).
- `range(x, y)` works a bit differently in Python 2 vs. Python 3.  I won't go into the details here, but I recommend using Python 3 (which hopefully you're already using).
- `range(x)` is will generate a range from (and including) zero up to (but *not* including) `x`.  So `range(x)` is basically the same as `range(0, x)`.
- The `range` function will generate a `range` object; that is, it doesn't actually create a `list` of all the integers between `x` and `y`.  If you do want a `list` of integers between `x` and `y`, use this code:

  ```
  some_list = list(range(x, y))
  ```

However, if you're looking to pull out a slice of values out of a sequential container, this might work:

```
from itertools import islice
values = islice(df.iloc, 1, 5)  # returns an iterator
values = list(values)  # extracts the values from the iterator into a list
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's slicing syntax doesn't produce a range of integers; it produces one or more `slice` objects which are passed to the `__getitem__` method of the appropriate type. That is,

```
df.iloc[1:4]
```

is equivalent to either

```
def.iloc[slice(1,4)]
```

or

```
df.iloc.__getitem__(slice(1,4))
```